# How can the average time for all users be greater than either the average time on page for ‘Desktop and Tablet’ or the ‘Tablet’ users?

Tags: ios, web, google-analytics, traffic

How can the average time for all users be greater than either the average time on page for ‘Desktop and Tablet’ or the ‘Tablet’ users? Could there be something else that is contributing to the users’ average time on the page?
Please see the following Google Analytics data, thank you very much!

For http://test1.com the Avg. Time on page:

All users – 2:10

Mobile – 0:00

Desktop and Tablet – 1:11

Tablet – 1:25

For http://test2.com the Avg. Time on page:

All users – 1:51

Mobile – 0:00

Desktop and Tablet – 1:22

Tablet – 1:27

Please see the following screenshot：
[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 'Average Time on Page' is a relative value. More than 'Desktop and Tablet' and 'Tablet' users intersect, so these lines must be analysed separately.

Formula for Average Time on Page for chosen period:

*Average Time on Page = Time on Page/(Page Views - Exits)*

For example this week:

Desktop users:
Time on Page = 100 s, Page Views excluding Exits = 20, Average Time on Page = 5 s

All users:
Time on Page = 500 s, Page Views excluding Exits = 50, Average Time on Page = 10 s